# Illegal characters in path c# - XmlTextWriter

Tags: c#

I am using XmlTextWriter and get an error while loading URL from rest service. The error is "illegal characters in path". I have tried using @"https://www.foo.com/foobar/rest-1/Data/Test?sel=GeneratedFrom&find=TS-01108&findin=Parent.Number"

When I step through with debugger I see the value has quotations, but I suspect it might be either the "?", "=", "&" or "." perhaps.

```
string URL = "https://www.foo.com/foobar/rest-1/Data/Test?sel=GeneratedFrom&find=TS-01108&findin=Parent.Number";

string XML_FILENAME = URL + ".xml";

        WebResponse response = utils.GetRestResponse(URL);
        if (response != null)
        {
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream()));

            // Illegal characters in path happens here
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(XML_FILENAME, null);
```

Comment: you need a file, not a url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of the first XmlTextWriter initializer parameter. If a string parameter is passed there, that should be a filename not a web resource.

Comment: It works when I use "https://www.foo.com/foobar/rest-1/Data/Test/12345". Then it gives me all the data for the "Test" 12345 or https://www.foo.com/foobar/rest-1/Data/Test would return all attribute values for all of the tests. So, I could just load the xml data for all of the tests and get specific data that way. I was just trying to see if I could get away with loading a specific set of data from the query. Thank you for clarifying, it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.foo.com/foobar/rest-1/Data/Test?sel=GeneratedFrom&find=TS-01108&findin=Parent.Number

Is not a legal file name, change it to something else. When the xml file is written to the disk it needs a legal name, your name is contains illegal characters. Try to create a text file with that name and windows will complain.